# How to copy 1 column from a 2d Array and put it into a 1d Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to put the names of 1 column from a 2d array into a String 1d array called names, but its getting repeated 5 times. I can't seem to make it appear once, any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

```
// a 2d array list obtained from a file
Monica - 23
Mike - 24
Adam - 44
Mark - 78
Beth - 78
```

```java
public static String [] sortName (String [] [] data) {

        // Sort the names and put it in a 1d array

        //[rows] [col]

        String [] names = new String [5];
        for (int n = 0; n < names.length; n++) {
            for (int q = 0; q < 5; q++ ) {
            names [n] = data[q] [0];

                // Print to see if it works
              System.out.println(names[n]);
                    }
              }

        return names;
    }
```

```
//output
Monica
Mike
Adam
Mark
Beth
Monica
Mike
Adam
Mark
Beth
Monica
Mike
Adam
Mark
Beth
Monica
Mike
Adam
Mark
Beth
Monica
Mike
Adam
Mark
Beth
```

Comment: Can you put 2D array sample: "Monica - 23" is not 2D array, for string 2d array its like [["hello", "world"],["sample", "world"]].

Comment: Why do you need two loops, Just iterate it for number of rows and for every rows just take data[i][0];

Comment: Your names array has a length of 5, so it will loop 5 times in your first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your names array has a length of 5, so it will loop 5 times in your first loop. You need to change it to data.length instead.

You need to change it to this:

```
public static String[] sortName(String[][] data)
{
    // Sort the names and put it in a 1d array
    // [rows] [col]

    String[] names = new String[data.length]; // <------ This needs to be the data.length and not 5.

    for (int n = 0; n < names.length; n++)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < data.length; q++)
        {
            names[n] = data[q][0];

            // Print to see if it works
            System.out.println(names[n]);
        }
    }

    return names;
}
```